# Sending PDF as attachment for offline syncing

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

We have a mobile app that works in offline mode.
It stores all the user data (Multiple forms, around 20 columns) in SQLite and whenever internet connection is available, it sends all these records to server.

The server (Laravel / PHP) reads these records, loops them, generates a PDF for every record and sends email to each record with generated PDF as attachment.

I want to know what is the best practices for the above? Because script is going to take lot of time if it has to generate PDFs for 100 or more records.

I have integrated Mailgun for sending emails but storing data and generating PDFs is taking lot of time.

Should I generate PDF on app and send to server in base64 form?

Comment: What do you mean by "best practise"? What's the problem with the given queue-based approach?

Comment: Well, you can use cron jobs for this if you like, which handles 10 PDFs in it's single request. But why 1 PDF email per record? Isn't it like spamming the receiver's inbox?

Comment: I'm syncing 10 different records with 10 different email ids